# Allow middle bootstrap button to grow and fill width

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">text</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </html>
```

How can I let the button with text grow and fill only available space?

I have tried making button block button but it takes more than available space. I have also tried setting text button width in percentage but that is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap classes: `d-inline-flex w-100 justify-content-between` for buttons parent container and `w-100 mx-2` for text button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-inline-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  w-100 mx-2">text</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your buttons in a class then display it as `flex`, then give your middle button a width 100%. it will fill the available area.

See flexbox docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```
.button-full {
    display: flex;
}
.btn-fill {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```css
.button-full {
    display: flex;
}
.button-full.all > button {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.btn-fill {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
1 -
    <div class="row">
   
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 button-full">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-fill">text</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
     </div>
    2 - .button-full .all
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 button-full all">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-minus"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">text</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fas fa-plus"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why did you solve it and I couldnt - I have also tried flex but there were no more padding left between the 1 and 2 and 2 3 buttons. I was using Bootstrap flex though